# socket.rb:206:in `bind': Address already in use - bind(2) for 127.0.0.1:3000 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I am getting the following error when I run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails s`

> `bind': Address already in use - bind(2) for 127.0.0.1:3000 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)

I have tried some of the other post, from where I found the following command `rails s -p 3001` This works for localhost:3001 but when I push to heroku I get the following error when I go to my url. I am guessing there's maybe an issue with my database.yml file since it has given me some issues.

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.

rails -v  Rails 4.2.1
ruby -v ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-darwin15]

database.yml

```html
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: vlog_development


test:
  <<: *default
  database: vlog_test


production:
  <<: *default
  database: vlog_production
  username:
  password:
```

Comment: Are you getting the same error on heroku? `'bind': Address already in use - bind(2)`

Comment: no, in Heroku when I input some data into a form field and then press enter I get the error were sorry but something went wrong.

Comment: https://gentle-fjord-81780.herokuapp.com/apps/texty try it here and you would see

Comment: @Emu if I run ```rails s -p 3001``` the application works but when I run it from production environment it gives me the error bind(2)

Comment: Your default `3000` port is busy somehow. Use `netstat` to grep the 3000 port and then kill the running application on that port.

Comment: run `heroku logs` command in your terminal and paste output here. i don't think heroku is giving you error because of busy port.

Comment: @Emu but why isn't running on heroku?

Comment: 2016-12-01T05:38:56.528956+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 54901 -e production`
2016-12-01T05:39:03.130523+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2016-12-01T05:39:03.089288+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-12-01 05:39:03] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2016-12-01T05:39:03.089319+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-12-01 05:39:03] INFO  ruby 2.2.0 (2014-12-25) [x86_64-linux]
2016-12-01T05:39:03.089707+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-12-01 05:39:03] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=4 port=54901

Comment: In your local machine the port is used by some other application. To fine what's happening in heroku's `something went wrong` error, you need to check the error log. You can get the log from `production.log` file in server.

Comment: as per the logs you pasted, heroku is able to start server but something happing after that, may be there is something breaking in your code. please update whole error log in question for better understanding.

Comment: I just deleted my heroku app and the git folder and created it again when I run ```rails server``` I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is because of your default 3000 port is busy.Use command "ps" on terminal


    PID TTY          TIME CMD
     4662 pts/5    00:00:00 bash
     4975 pts/5    00:00:03 ruby
     4982 pts/5    00:00:00 ps

Then kill process by command on terminal sudo kill -9 PID. Then start your server again.
```

Comment: when I run ```ps``` I get something different

Comment: ```PID TTY           TIME CMD
15269 ttys001    0:00.04 /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2 --server
15272 ttys001    0:00.07 -bash```

Comment: I fixed it after running ```lsof -i :3000``` and then ```kill -9 4299```

Comment: however I am not getting the following error ```Missing `secret_token` and `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set these values in `config/secrets.yml```

Comment: I'm getting a similar problem [^1] using `$bundler exec jekyll serve`. Here's how I solved it: 1) `sudo netstat -anp | grep 4000`; 2) Identify the PID associated with 'jekyll' 3) `sudo kill -9 PID`  [^1] "/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.0.0/socket.rb:201:in bind: Address already in use - bind(2) for 127.0.0.1:4000 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)"